# Regex - Capturing repeating groups excluding surrounding partially matching content

Tags: r, regex, pcre, repeat

For the record, I am using R, but the queries I have are platform independent (as it stands) so I'll demo with regex101. I am attempting to capture repeated groups that may or may not be surrounded by other text. So the ideal behaviour is shown in this demo:
[demo1](https://regex101.com/r/7bpvOp/4)

regex: `(\d{2})(AB)`

text: `blahblah11AB12AB13ABblah`

So it nicely captures all the groups I want:

Match 1

```
Full match  8-12    `11AB`
Group 1.    8-10    `11`
Group 2.    10-12   `AB`
```

Match 2

```
Full match  12-16   `12AB`
Group 1.    12-14   `12`
Group 2.    14-16   `AB`
```

Match 3

```
Full match  16-20   `13AB`
Group 1.    16-18   `13`
Group 2.    18-20   `AB`
```

However, if I include another piece of matched text, it captures that as well (which is fair enough I suppose)

text: `blahblah11AB12AB13ABblah22AB`
returns the same but with the extra group:

Match 4

```
Full match  24-28   `22AB`
Group 1.    24-26   `22`
Group 2.    26-28   `AB`
```

[demo2](https://regex101.com/r/7bpvOp/5)

What I want to do is capture the first group but disregard all other text, even if there is a subsequent match. In essence, I want to get just the three matches from this text: `blahblah11AB12AB13ABblah22AB`

I have tried a number of things, such as this:
`(((\d{2})(AB))+)(.*)`

But then I get the following, which loses all both the last group capture:

[Demo 3](https://regex101.com/r/7bpvOp/6)

Match 1

```
Full match  8-28    `11AB12AB13ABblah22AB`
Group 1.    8-20    `11AB12AB13AB`
Group 2.    16-20   `13AB`
Group 3.    16-18   `13`
Group 4.    18-20   `AB`
Group 5.    20-28   `blah22AB`
```

I need something which retains the repeated groups. Am stumped!

In R, the output should look like this:

```
[[1]]
     [,1]   [,2] [,3]
[1,] "11AB" "11" "AB"
[2,] "12AB" "12" "AB"
[3,] "13AB" "13" "AB"
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: To clarify, it's not a set number of matches you want, but all consecutive matches?

Comment: Correct @camille

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An idea would be to [use `\G` for chaining matches](https://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html) to `^` start and [reset by `\K`](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-php.html#K) after.

```
(?:^.*?\K|\G)(\d{2})(AB)
```

- `^.*?\K` will match any amount of any characters lazily before the first match
- `|\G` or continue at the end of previous match which can be: start, first, previous

[See your updated demo](https://regex101.com/r/7bpvOp/7)

This will match the first chain of matches and is a pcre pattern (`perl=TRUE`).
If there can only be non-digits before first match, [use `^\D*\K` instead](https://regex101.com/r/7bpvOp/8) of `^.*?\K`.

Comment: You have cracked it! Many thanks. That gives me exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, the problem is in the placement of the parenthesis.

```
pattern <- "(\\d{2}AB)"

s <- "blahblah11AB12AB13ABbla"

m <- gregexpr(pattern, s)
regmatches(s, m)
#[[1]]
#[1] "11AB" "12AB" "13AB"


s2 <- "blahblah11AB12AB13ABblah22AB"
s3 <- "11AB12AB13ABblah22AB"

S <- c(s, s2, s3)

m <- gregexpr(pattern, S)
regmatches(S, m)
#[[1]]
#[1] "11AB" "12AB" "13AB"
#
#[[2]]
#[1] "11AB" "12AB" "13AB" "22AB"
#
#[[3]]
#[1] "11AB" "12AB" "13AB" "22AB"
```

Note that many times this is run in one code line only. I have left it like this to make it more clear.

**EDIT.**

Maybe the following does what the OP is asking for.
I bet there are better solutions, it seems to me that two regex's are an overkill.

```
pattern <- "((\\d{2}AB)+)([^[:digit:]AB]+(\\d{2}AB))"
pattern2 <- "(\\d{2}AB)"

m <- gregexpr(pattern2, gsub(pattern, "\\1", S))
regmatches(S, m)
#[[1]]
#[1] "11AB" "12AB" "13AB"
#
#[[2]]
#[1] "11AB" "12AB" "13AB"
#
#[[3]]
#[1] "11AB" "12AB" "13AB"
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. I have edited my post to show what I am looking for in R

Comment: So, the issue is that I want to submit text in s2 or s3 and return the output you produced from s. If that makes sense. So it ignores blah22AB..

Answer (score 0):

You could use the quantifier `{3}` to get just the 3 firsts groups: `(((\d{2})(AB)){3})`. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Yj9mx8/1)